# Display Alert inside function call not working Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to display an alert with the change of my count on button click.
My code is as below-
this is my click event

```
Clicked = () => {
    this.setState({
        count:this.state.count+1
    })
    if(this.state.count >5){
        return <Alerts msg="First"/>
    }else{
        return <Alerts msg="Too much size"/>
    }
}
```

My button-

```
 render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Button onClick={this.Clicked}>Click Me</Button>
        </div>
    )
```

Alert.js-

```
export default function Alerts(props) {
         return (
              <div>
                 <Alert severity="warning">{props.msg}</Alert>
              </div>
        );
      }
```

But my Alert is not showing. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Modify `clicked` function like this:-

```
Clicked = () => {
    this.setState({
        count:this.state.count+1
    })
}
```

And inside render add the logic to render `alert`:-

```
 render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Button onClick={this.Clicked}>Click Me</Button>
    {this.state.count >5 ? <Alerts msg="First"/> :  <Alerts msg="Too much size"/>}
        </div>
)

}
```

Edit: You can create a separate function for rendering of `alert` and call in render like this:-

```
renderAlert = () => {
  if(this.state.count > 5) return <Alerts msg="First"/>
  return <Alerts msg="Too much size"/>
}


render() { 
          <div>
            <Button onClick={this.Clicked}>Click Me</Button>
            {renderAlert()}
        </div>
 }
```

Comment: I do not want to use the conditional rendering. Is there any way I could do it inside the click function? I may have nested if else so I can't add it in the conditional render

Comment: In order to add your element to the `DOM` you have to add the respective element inside render. You cannot do it inside onClick function but you can create a new  function, apply the logic inside that and call that function inside render.

Comment: could you show me how in the above example please? @maya_nk99

Comment: @Preeti Edited the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous. So you can't access the count value soon after updating it. Also, you are trying to return the component from event handler.
Either you can assign the return statement to some state or directly access in return statement of component.

```
render() {
    const alertMessage =
      this.state.count > 5 ? (
        <Alerts msg="First" />
      ) : (
        <Alerts msg="Too much size" />
      );

    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.Clicked}>Click Me</Button>
        {this.state.count ? alertMessage : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Check this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-paper-89oqo?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you separate the handling of state and the rendering of Alert. So you handle state in the Clicked function and the returning of Alerts in the render. So you would have something like this.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }
  }

  Clicked = () => {
    // Only handle the setState in the function
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Button onClick={this.Clicked} variant="contained">Add One</Button>

        <div>Count: {this.state.count}</div>

        {/* Handle displaying Alerts in the render */}
        {
          this.state.count < 5
          ? <Alerts msg="First"/>
          : <Alerts msg="Too much size"/>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here's a code sandbox with an example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-brattain-p6w7z?file=/src/App.js)